# Am I checking for correlation or difference? If so, how shall I do it?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likert

As a start- I appreciate any advice you can offer me with this question, and want to thank you for your assistance in advance.
I have A-level maths knowledge, although did not like statistics. Statistics are not in my daily activities and this is the first time I have attempted to conduct statistical analysis in over 4 years - so it will be clear that I am not entirely sure what I am doing!

I have conducted a questionnaire which was completed pre- and post- a mandatory activity (for all participants) in their education and would like to assess whether there has been a statistically significant change in rating of statements using Likert data:
1 “Strongly disagree”
2 “Somewhat disagree”
3 “Neither agree not Disagree”
4 “Somewhat agree”
5 “Strongly agree”
I hypothesise that post-intervention there should be an increase in confidence (and therefore more strongly agree with the statements)

Firstly, I believe that my Likert scale data should be analysed as ordinal rather than interval data as the intervals are not even between "strongly, somewhat, neither".

Secondly, is there a dependent variable? Is the Likert data the 'outcome' data, that is being measured, and therefore is dependent on the intervention that was carried out (even though everyone received it)?

Thirdly, does the fact that there is a different number of respondents pre- and post- intervention matter, and that they are not necessarily the same participants, as long as I recognise this in my methods? I cannot say that the same people responded, so can I really say that the intervention made a significant difference, or am I rather commenting on the general trend?

Before writing this I thought that:

- I am testing for correlation (within a group)
- There is no dependent variable
- My data is continuous, ordered & categorical data
- And therefore should be analysed using Spearman's rho correlation.

However, when researching further to write this question, I now think I believe that:

- I am checking for difference (between groups)
- I have an ordinal dependent variable.
- I have a repeated measurement (pre- and post-intervention)
- I only have 1 group
- And therefore should use a Mann-Whitney test.

Any assistance with this would be hugely appreciated.
I hope it makes sense - please ask for more information if necessary.